# Can you implicitly construct a non-Borel subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\overline{X} = \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I'm just now reading into measure theory and the idea of a $\sigma$ algebra. My textbook says implicit constructions of non-Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with AOC are possible.  Can you construct such a non-Borel subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\overline{X} = \mathbb{R}$?

If so, how would you go about such a construction?

Comment: The set of all members of $(0,1)$ mapped to zero by an [infinite parity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_function#Infinite_version) is non-Borel but clearly dense in $(0, 1)$. Just use your favorite continuous mapping from $(0,1)\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ on this set.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to construct such a set even without the axiom of choice, but the axiom of choice certainly makes it easier:

First construct any non-Borel set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. For example, the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) is a construction by first partitioning $\mathbb{R}$ into the subsets $\{a+\mathbb{Q}:a\in\mathbb{R}\}$, then from each set $a+\mathbb{Q}$ choosing a distinct member to form the set $A$. This $A$ is not even in the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, so it's not in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. There are other wats to make such $A$ (and even ways without invoking the axiom of choice), so I'll assume that you've seen at least one.

Then the key observation is, we can make $A$ into a dense set without losing its non-Borel-ness! Consider the set $B=A\cup\mathbb{Q}$, which is certainly dense in $\mathbb{R}$. If $B$ were Borel, then note that $A\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable set and hence Borel, and $A=(B\setminus\mathbb{Q})\cup(A\cap\mathbb{Q})$ is the union of two Borel sets and hence Borel, a contradiction.

This $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is what you wanted.

Comment: +1 for this fine answer, though of course without AC one has to be very careful about saying that particular sets are non-Borel...

Comment: Or $A=B\setminus(\mathbb Q\setminus A)$.